# Is TPL Dataflow BufferBlock thread safe?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I have a fairly simple producer-consumer pattern where (simplified) I have two producers who produce output that is to be consumed by one consumer.

For this I use [`System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Thread%20Safety)

A `BufferBlock` object is created. One `Consumer` is listening to this `BufferBlock`, and processes any received input.

Two 'Producers`send data to the`BufferBlock` simultaneously

Simplified:

```
BufferBlock<int> bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();

async Task Consume()
{
    while(await bufferBlock.OutputAvailable())
    {
         int dataToProcess = await outputAvailable.ReceiveAsync();
         Process(dataToProcess);
    }
}

async Task Produce1()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbersToProcess = ...;
    foreach (int numberToProcess in numbersToProcess)
    {
         await bufferBlock.SendAsync(numberToProcess);
         // ignore result for this example
    }
}

async Task Produce2()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbersToProcess = ...;
    foreach (int numberToProcess in numbersToProcess)
    {
         await bufferBlock.SendAsync(numberToProcess);
         // ignore result for this example
    }
}
```

I'd like to start the Consumer first and then start the Producers as separate tasks:

```
var taskConsumer = Consume(); // do not await yet
var taskProduce1 = Task.Run( () => Produce1());
var taskProduce2 = Task.Run( () => Produce2());

// await until both producers are finished:
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {taskProduce1, taskProduce2});
bufferBlock.Complete(); // signal that no more data is expected in bufferBlock

// await for the Consumer to finish:
await taskConsumer;
```

At first glance, this is exactly how the producer-consumer was meant: several producers produce data while a consumer is consuming the produced data.

Yet, [BufferBlock about thread safety](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Thread%20Safety) says:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

And I thought that the P in TPL meant Parallel!
Should I worry? Is my code not thread safe?
Is there a different TPL Dataflow class that I should use?

Comment: The "Thread Safety" section in MSDN articles is notoriously unreliable.  Just copy/pasta from an article template, the author tends to not get enough info from the devs to make it more accurate.  Do keep in mind that just because DataBlock is thread-safe does not automagically make your own code thread-safe as well.  Something like the Count property is quite worthless when another thread is busy adding items.  Hopefully obvious but not explicitly stated in the docs.

Comment: Why the `BufferBlock` instead of an `ActionBlock`? The `async Task Consume()` could be replaced with just the `Process(...)` call  e.g. the `ActionBLock<int>(x => Process(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [`BufferBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) class is thread safe. I can't back this claim by pointing to an official document, because the "Thread Safety" section has been removed from the documentation. But I can see in the source that the class contains a lock object for synchronizing the incoming messages:

```
/// <summary>Gets the lock object used to synchronize incoming requests.</summary>
private object IncomingLock { get { return _source; } }
```

When the [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) extension method is called ([source code](https://source.dot.net/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Base/DataflowBlock.cs.html#6f1a03e2b2aaa562)), the explicitly implemented `ITargetBlock.OfferMessage` method is invoked ([source code](https://source.dot.net/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Blocks/BufferBlock.cs.html)). Below is an excerpt of this method:

```
DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<T>.OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader,
    T messageValue, ISourceBlock<T> source, bool consumeToAccept)
{
    //...
    lock (IncomingLock)
    {
        //...
        _source.AddMessage(messageValue);
        //...
    }
}
```

It would be strange indeed if this class, or any other `XxxBlock` class included in the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library, was not thread-safe. It would severely hamper the ease of use of this great library.

Answer (score 1):

I think an `ActionBlock<T>` would better suit what your doing since it has a built in buffer that many producers can send data in through. The default block options process the data on single background task but you can set a new value for parallelism and bounded capacity. With `ActionBlock<T>` the main area of concern to ensure thread safety will be in the delegate you pass that processes each message. The operation of that function has to be independent of each message, i.e. not modifying shared state just like any `Parrallel...` function.

```
public class ProducerConsumer
{
    private ActionBlock<int> Consumer { get; }

    public ProducerConsumer()
    {
        Consumer = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Process(x));            
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var producer1Tasks = Producer1();
        var producer2Tasks = Producer2();
        await Task.WhenAll(producer1Tasks.Concat(producer2Tasks));
        Consumer.Complete();
        await Consumer.Completion;
    }

    private void Process(int data)
    {
        // process
    }

    private IEnumerable<Task> Producer1() => Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => Consumer.SendAsync(x));

    private IEnumerable<Task> Producer2() => Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => Consumer.SendAsync(x));
}
```

Comment: My concer is about thread safety of ActionBlock.SendAsync function: two different threads call ActionBlock.SendAsync on the same ActionBlock object. The ActionBlock class mentions the same remark about thread safety as BufferBlock: SendAsync is not thread safe. What makes you think ActionBlock is more thread safe than BufferBlock?

Comment: That remark is a generic warning that only static methods are guaranteed to be thread safe. That said though, if two threads call `SendAsync` on the same `Acton/Buffer Block` then two messages are queued for insertion into the blocks input buffer. `SendAsync` is itself threadsafe for multiple producers so long as the block option [SingleProducerConstrained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.singleproducerconstrained(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to `false`, which is default behavior.